# Prove a set is dense in $\mathbb{R}^+$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

An exercise asks me to prove:

$$\left\{\dfrac{p^2+q^2}{2p^3+q},(p,q)\in\mathbb{N^*}^2\right\}$$
is dense in $\mathbb{R^+}$.

I guess I'm supposed to represent all $q\in\mathbb{Q^+}$ by its elements, but I failed to find such a construction. Could someone give a help?

Thanks a lot~

Comment: No, you don't need to show that you can represent every rational number this way. You only need to show that you can get *arbitrarily close* to any (rational) number with such numbers.

Comment: @TedShifrin You mean I could try to construct a sequence converging to all rational numbers?

Comment: Maybe you need to show that for every open interval $I$ contains some points of the given set

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan So how to think over this idea? Is it for any element x, I could find a point in this set arbitrarily close to x?

Comment: The idea is that as $p\rightarrow \infty $ then $\dfrac{p^2+q^2}{2p^3+q}\rightarrow 0$ and when q grows then $\dfrac{p^2+q^2}{2p^3+q}$ increases like a linear function. So firstly you take $p$ very large and then you increase $q$ to land in any interval

Comment: @clark -- Very nice; almost sure to work (with some work).

Comment: @clark I think it may has a problem. Say we wanna approach a big number, we have to make q greater than p, and the quasi-linearity doesn't stand...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $f(q)=\dfrac{p^2+q^2}{2p^3+q}$ then we take its derivative
$$f'(q)=\dfrac{2q(2p^3+q) -p^2-q^2}{(2p^3+q)^2}>0$$
Now, whenever $q\leq p^2$ we find the very crude bound 
$f'(q) \leq \dfrac{6p^5}{4p^6}=\dfrac{3}{2p}$.
Using the mean value theorem we obtain $ f(q+1) -f(q) =f'(\xi) \leq \dfrac{3}{2 p}  $. Therefore, we can go from $f(1)$ to $f(p^2)$ using jumps of order $1/p$.
However, $f(p^2)=\dfrac{p^2+p^4}{2p^3+p^2}$ which is of order $p$.

To sum up, as $p$ is going to infinity $f(1)\rightarrow 0$, the length of the successive step is going to zero and the final point we can reach namely $f(p^2)$ is going to infinity. Which concludes the result.